# The INSERT statement conflicted with constraint fk_Transaction_ctmID_Customer_ctmID. The conflict occurred in column 'ctmID'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I got this error when trying to save checkout to database. Honestly I don't know how to fix this and I don't know where it comes from. Please help me.

Here's the whole error I got

> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_Transaction_ctmID_Customer_ctmID". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-WebsiteEntities-20210902054356", table "dbo.User_Customer", column 'ctmID'.

My `Transaction` table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transaction] 
(
    [transID]         INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ctmID]           INT NULL,
    [invoice_bill]    INT NULL,
    [invoice_payment] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [invoice_date]    DATE NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([transID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [fk_Transaction_ctmID_Customer_ctmID] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([ctmID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User_Customer] ([ctmID])
);
```

My `User_Customer` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User_Customer] 
(
    [userId]             NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    [ctmID]              INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ctm_firstname]      NVARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    [ctm_lastname]       NVARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    [ctm_email]          NVARCHAR(256) NULL,
    [ctm_phone]          NVARCHAR(10)  NULL,
    [ctm_gender]         NVARCHAR(3)   NOT NULL,
    [ctm_doB]            DATE          NULL,
    [ctm_address]        NVARCHAR(256) NULL,
    [ctm_cardtype]       NVARCHAR(15)  NOT NULL,
    [ctm_creditID]       NVARCHAR(16)  NULL,
    [ctm_cardexpmonth]   DATE          NULL,
    [ctm_cardexpyear]    DATE          NULL,
    [ctm_billingaddress] NVARCHAR(50)  NULL,
    [ctm_cardvalidation] NVARCHAR(4)   NULL,
    [ctm_regisDay]       DATE DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ctmID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [fk_Customer_userId_AspNetUsers_ID] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([userId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
);
```

Class `User_Customer`:

```
public partial class User_Customer
{
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public User_Customer()
        {
            Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
            Products = new HashSet<Product>();
            Transactions = new HashSet<Transaction>();
        }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(128)]
        public string userId { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public int ctmID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string ctm_firstname { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string ctm_lastname { get; set; }

        [StringLength(256)]
        public string ctm_email { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10)]
        public string ctm_phone { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(3)]
        public string ctm_gender { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime? ctm_doB { get; set; }

        [StringLength(256)]
        public string ctm_address { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(15)]
        public string ctm_cardtype { get; set; }

        [StringLength(16)]
        public string ctm_creditID { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime? ctm_cardexpmonth { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime? ctm_cardexpyear { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string ctm_billingaddress { get; set; }

        [StringLength(4)]
        public string ctm_cardvalidation { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime ctm_regisDay { get; set; }

        public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}
```

Class Transaction

```
public partial class Transaction
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Transaction()
    {
        Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int transID { get; set; }

    public int ctmID { get; set; }

    public int invoice_bill { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string invoice_payment { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime invoice_date { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public virtual User_Customer User_Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my `ProductController`:

```
public ActionResult Checkout(string contact, string address)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        List<Cart> li2 = TempData["cart"] as List<Cart>;

        User_Customer ctm = new User_Customer();

        Transaction iv = new Transaction();
        iv.ctmID = Convert.ToInt32(ctm.ctmID);
        iv.invoice_date = System.DateTime.Now;
        iv.invoice_bill = (int)TempData["total"];
        iv.invoice_payment = "cash";

        db.Transactions.Add(iv);
        db.SaveChanges();

        foreach (var item in li2)
        {
            Order od = new Order();
            od.productID = item.productID;
            od.ctm_email = contact;
            od.ctm_address = address;
            od.order_day = System.DateTime.Now;
            od.transID = iv.transID;
            od.order_qty = item.cart_qty;
            od.order_unit = item.cart_price;
            od.order_payment = item.cart_bill;

            db.Orders.Add(od);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        TempData.Remove("total");
        TempData.Remove("cart");

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    TempData.Keep();
    return View();
}
```

Here is my `Checkout.cshtml` view:

```
<section class="ftco-section ftco-cart">
        @if (TempData["total"] == null)
        {
            <h1>cart is empty</h1>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Products")">go back</a>
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 ftco-animate">
                        <div class="cart-list">
                            <h3>Total Item : @TempData["item_count"]</h3>
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead class="thead-primary">
                                    <tr class="text-center">
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th>ID</th>
                                        <th>Product Name</th>
                                        <th>Price</th>
                                        <th>Qty</th>
                                        <th>Total</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    @foreach (var item in TempData["cart"] as List<WebsiteEntities.Models.Cart>)
                                    {
                                        <tr class="text-center">
                                            <td class="product-remove"><a href="@Url.Action("Remove", "Products", new { id = item.productID })"><span class="ion-ios-close"></span></a></td>
                                            <td class="product-name">
                                                <h3>@item.productID</h3>
                                            </td>

                                            <td class="product-name">
                                                <h3>@item.product_name</h3>

                                            </td>

                                            <td class="price">@item.cart_price</td>

                                            <td class="quantity">
                                                @item.cart_qty
                                            </td>

                                            <td class="total">@item.cart_bill$</td>
                                        </tr><!-- END TR-->
                                    }
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row justify-content-end">

                    <div class="col-lg-4 mt-5 cart-wrap ftco-animate">
                        <div class="cart-total mb-3">
                            <h3>Cart Totals</h3>
                            <hr>
                            <p class="d-flex total-price">
                                <span>Total</span>
                                <span>@TempData["total"]$</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        @if (TempData["cart"] != null)
                        {
                        using (Html.BeginForm())
                        {

                        <input type="submit" value="Checkout" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-4" />
                        }
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </section>
```

Everything was working great until I added

```
@if (TempData["cart"] != null)
{
    using(Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <input type="submit" value="Checkout" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-4" />
    }
}
```

Error will occur immediately

Answer (score 0):

When your Checkout() method saves changes to the [Transaction] table, the ctmID field you have set in your Transaction POCO class like below:

```
iv.ctmID = Convert.ToInt32(ctm.ctmID);
```

does not have an existing user key ctmID within the [User_Customer] table.

The ctmID field within your [User_Customer] table has to reference an existing key within the [AspNetUsers] table.

Ensure that you set the ctmID value in your Transaction table to a value within the [AspNetUsers] table then the keys will be referenced correctly between your entities when you insert records into the [Transaction] table.

Comment: So how can I fix it? Will iv.ctmID = cmt.cmtID will work?

Comment: Your application needs to obtain the current user id, name or email (e.g. from HttpContext or the User property from the controller), then pass that into the Checkout() method. You can then query the AspNetUsers table directly or use the ASP.NET Identity API to get the user object (i.e. UserManager.FindByIdAsync()). Then set cmt.cmtID to the id of the user.